# I replaced a light fixture, now one specific outlet doesn’t work and the light fixture goes dim when something is plugged in

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, light-fixture

Here’s the layout: there is a light fixture at the top of the stairs.  There is one switch for this fixture at the bottom of the stairs and one at the top. On an adjacent wall up stairs, there is an outlet near the floor.  Before I replaced anything, everything was working properly. Neither switch is a dimmer.

I was told this house was built in the 1940’s.

I replaced the light fixture at the top of the stairs. I have done this before in this house without issue.  I removed the old fixture and wired in the new white wire to a group of 3 other white wires. I wired the black wire with a group of 2 black wires.  Each group was capped with a wire nut.  I connected the bare copper ground to the box above the fixture.

I turned the breaker back on and the switches operated the fixture properly.  I moved on to another project.   But then, weeks later, we plugged something in to a rarely used outlet near the fixture and the light on the fixture went from off to on without the switch being touched.  I flipped the switch yet the light stayed on.  Plus, the vacuum we plugged in to the outlet never turned on.  I tested with a fan and got the same result.

I rechecked the wiring and everything looked right to me, but clearly something is not right.  The new fixture has an LED bulb.  I read online that LED bulbs can do funny things in old houses.  I replaced the bulb with an incandescent one. Now, when the outlet is used, the outlet cycles on for 1 second, then off for one second.  The incandescent bulb does the same. Turning the switch off turns both the light and the outlet off.

I then unplugged the fan from the outlet and the light works fine with both the incandescent and the LED.

I understand pictures may be helpful but I have not taken any yet.  Would pictures of only the fixture wiring help?  Or would pictures of the outlet and switches be needed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Adding pictures of fixture wiring. Also, I was mistaken.  There are 3 groups of wires.  What look like 2 black groups and 1 white group.  I *think* I connected the new white and black where the old ones were but it’s possible I confused them.

[image: fixture]

Having trouble uploading non hi def photos:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CDmM5FSk4rcvtMnu9

[image: Downstairs switch]

[image: upstairs switch]

[image: outlet wiring]

I added photos of the wiring to the switches and the receptacle.  New info: I got a little zap when taking the photo of the receptacle.   I thought it was on the same breaker as the light but apparently not.  Maybe this is helpful.

Comment: Definitely pictures of the fixture wiring (since that's where you did the recent work), but pictures of switch and receptacle wiring may be helpful too.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring in all boxes involved please?

Comment: If you did not simply remove the old fixture wires (leaving the rest of the connections as they were) and replace with the new fixture wires, there's a wide range of possibles to debug. And presumably you didn't take pictures before removing the old fixture? (I hope to be wrong, but am usually right with that presumption.) [edit] to add pictures, use the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box to add them.

Comment: *You expected the wires in the box to be color-coded for your convenience*.  It's the exact opposite, they are intentionally miscolored specifically to confuse novices (well not really, but might as well be).  The only safe thing is to connect the new lamp's 2 wires to *exactly* the same place as the old lamp's 2 wires were attached.    Of course, even that can fail if *the last guy wired it wrong*.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes please?

Comment: I added 1 photo and 1 link to a photo.  I’m having trouble uploading the photos as they are too large.  I’m going to try to move the black wire from the fixture to the other black wire bundle.

Comment: More photos added.

Comment: Can you post photos that show the backs of the boxes involved?

Comment: Unfortunately this is all that the wiring allowed. I wanted to pull them out further.  What questions can I answer for you @ThreePhaseEel?

Comment: And thank you for your help @ThreePhaseEel and everyone. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Ben -- can you get in there closer with the camera (with the breaker off, of course)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can try.  What information are you looking for?  I will try to provide it.

Comment: @Ben -- I'm basically looking to see how the various wires are grouped together, as well as discerning information about what wiring method (wires in conduit, non-metallic sheathed cable, or armored cable) was used

Comment: The fact that you "got a zap" with the breaker off _does_ indicate that there are 2 breakers involved, and, if you've got wiring crossing from one circuit to another, you've created a _very_ dangerous situation! Go find the other breaker and make sure you turn it off, too! You may need to do some diagnostics with a multimeter to figure out which cable is on which breaker before reassembling everything.